# How to put user input into a SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database and I want the user to be able to have an input into what comes out. i.e

```
Select from Table where example = user input from box **(input by the user)**
```

Im guessing what I need is a variable to hold the value that then goes into the statement. I know how to get the value from the input box with script but can I use it like:

select * From handover WHERE hdate = variable. However I am guessing someone is going to talk to me about security if its even possible.

```
<html><body>

<input>User input</input> //That needs to go into statement


  <?php
 include 'config.php';

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM handover WHERE hdate = **user input**;");

 echo "<table border='1'>
   <tr>
 <th>hdate</th>
 <th>Delay</th>
 <th>Health and Safety</th>
 <th>Non Vsa</th>
 <th>VSA</th>
 <th>Dar</th>
 <th>Other</th>
<th>Hour</th>
</tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['hdate'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['hdelay'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['hs'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['nv'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['vsa'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['dar'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['other'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['hour'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
 }

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Any help is welcome and advice on the best language to use for this.

Kind Regards

Fintan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, this question has nothing to do with javascript & ajax. so you can delete those tags.

you want to show/search data from mysql.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM handover WHERE hdate = '".$_POST['abc']."' ");
```

this is when you want to check if hdate column have exact data as user input ( $_POST['abc'] ).

and also don't forget to use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

you can learn common mysql pattern queries from here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: @charlietfl you can do it through ajax, but there were no indication to use them there. flintan wanted to learn about mysql pattern to search data. if you want to do through ajax, try this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707648/)  nothing against ajax. :)