# Call PHP function in ajax, Synchronous XMLHttpRequest deprecarted

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Completely new to [php](/questions/tagged/php)/[ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax). Every tutorial seems to be outdated in one way or another. Spent about 30 hours already trying to come up with a simple insert/retrieve script. Please help! Once i see the code working its alot easier for me to fiddle with it understand the documentation.

Im getting the following error.

```
[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.
```

My index.php relevant data, the error is on the `xmlhttp.open` line.

```
disp_data();
function disp_data(){

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "update.php?status=disp",false);
```

This is my update.php relevant code. On the tutorial, it is supposed to load my data upon refresh, but its blank. I'm not sure why the tutorial sets it to false, when the documentation ive read at w3schools seems I should make it true, but neither work.

```
$status = $_GET["status"];

if ($status == "disp") {
  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysqli_select_db($link, "checkbox");
```

### $res = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table1");

my full index.php

```
<div id ="disp_data"></div>

<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript">

(function() {
  var newXHR = null;

  function sendXHR(type, url, data, callback) {
    newXHR = new XMLHttpRequest() || new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    newXHR.open(type, url, true); // Use async = true to avoid bad user experience for waiting a Sychronous request that might block the UI.
    newXHR.send(data);

    newXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.status === 200 && this.readyState === 4) {
        callback(this.response); // Callback function to process the response.
      }
    };
  }

  sendXHR("GET", "update.php?status=disp", null, function(response) {
    document.getElementById("disp_data").innerHTML=newXHR.responseText;
  });

})();

</script>

</body>
```

my full update.php file

```
$status = $_GET["status"];
if($status=="disp")
{
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysqli_select_db($link,"checkbox");
$res = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM table1");

echo "<table>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";   echo $row["id"]; echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";  echo $row["name"];  echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";  echo $row["city"];  echo "</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez I changed it to true , and there is no error , but my data is still not showing

Comment: I've added some details in my answer.

Comment: @born2gamble your data is not showing because you do not show any data. Where's your `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` or `xmlhttp.onload`? Where does your PHP script output any information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `true` in the `async` parameter.

Something like this: `xmlhttp.open("GET", "update.php?status=disp", true);`.

See [`XMLHttpRequest.open()`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B).

You could use this helper function to make `XMLHttpRequest`.

**Works in all browsers, incluiding IE6.**

```
var newXHR = null;

function sendXHR(type, url, data, callback) {
  newXHR = new XMLHttpRequest() || new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  newXHR.open(type, url, true); // Use async = true to avoid bad user experience for waiting a Sychronous request that might block the UI.
  newXHR.send(data);
  newXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.status === 200 && this.readyState === 4) {
      callback(this.response); // Callback function to process the response.
    }
  };
}
```

Usage:

```
sendXHR("GET", "update.php?status=disp", null, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

You could retrieve data by using this demo:

```js
(function() {



  var newXHR = null;

  function sendXHR(type, url, data, callback) {
    newXHR = new XMLHttpRequest() || new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    newXHR.open(type, url, true); // Use async = true to avoid bad user experience for waiting a Sychronous request that might block the UI.
    newXHR.send(data);
    newXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.status === 200 && this.readyState === 4) {
        callback(this.response); // Callback function to process the response.
      }
    };
  }


  // Example 1: Get data.
  var btnRequest = document.getElementById("btnRequest");
  btnRequest.onclick = function() {
    sendXHR("GET", "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/22851f9c21733973b2705b0b65443f90/raw/30cf99ceeb470a7ab6d2ffb51a78f1bb57f41ca3/data.txt", null, function(response) {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = response; // response contains the data from the server.
    });
  };


  // Example 2. Cancel a long request.
  var btnCancelRequest = document.getElementById("btnCancelRequest");
  btnCancelRequest.onclick = function() {
    newXHR.abort(); // You can use the newXHR variable to abort a XMLHttpRequest that is taking long time to response, with the .abort() method.
  };





})();
```

```css
#myDiv {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnRequest" type="button">Request data</button>
<button id="btnCancelRequest" type="button">Cancel request</button>
<div id="myDiv">The new content will print here.</div>
```

---

It's good to know this:

> [**`XMLHttpRequest.response`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response) property returns the response's
>   body. It can be of the type `ArrayBuffer`, `Blob`, `Document`,
>   `JavaScript` object, or a `DOMString`, depending of the value of
>   `XMLHttpRequest.responseType` property. Value of response is null if
>   the request is not complete or was not successful. However, if the
>   value of `responseType` was set to `"text"` or the empty string,
>   response can contain the partial text response while the request is
>   still in the loading state.
>
> [**`XMLHttpRequest.responseText`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText) property returns a `DOMString`
>   that contains the response to the request as text, or `null` if the
>   request was unsuccessful or has not yet been sent. The `responseText`
>   property will have the partial response as it arrives even before the
>   request is complete. If `responseType` is set to anything other than
>   the empty `string` or `"text"`, accessing `responseText` will throw
>   `InvalidStateError` exception.

---

Your [php](/questions/tagged/php) code must be like this:

```
$status = $_GET["status"];
if($status=="disp")
{
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysqli_select_db($link,"checkbox");
    $res = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM table1");

    $html = "<table>"; // Declare a variable to concat the html content.
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
        $html += "<tr><td>";
        $html += $row["id"];
        $html += "</td><td>";
        $html += $row["name"];
        $html += "</td><td>";
        $html += $row["city"];
        $html += "</td></tr>";
    }
    $html += "</table>";
    echo $html; // Prints the $html variable.
}
```

In you [html](/questions/tagged/html) code you need to remove:

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

*It's not necessary if you gonna use native [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).*

Comment: Thanks I will try implementing this in a moment , my 9mo old woke up :/

Comment: No problem @born2gamble. If you need more examples let me know.

Comment: @born2gamble You can see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707648/using-jquery-ajax-to-retrieve-data-from-mysql.

Comment: That is working , it is showing up on the console !.. I have a div id that I was trying to display it to.. how would I do it using this method ?

Comment: Please include in your question the HTML markup and your php code to retrieve data.

Comment: Never mind , I understand a bit more now , and have it working now . Document.getElementById(“mydiv”).innerHTML =newXHR.responseText; .. correct ? (It works, just making sure that it’s the correct way)

Comment: @born2gamble JavaScript is case sensitive. The proper way is: `document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = newXHR.responseText;`.

Comment: = response; &  .newXHR.responseText are working the same. Is one better to use in this situation ?

Comment: *`XMLHttpRequest.responseText` property returns a `DOMString` that contains the response to the request as text, or null if the request was unsuccessful or has not yet been sent. The `responseText` property will have the partial response as it arrives even before the request is complete.*

Comment: *`XMLHttpRequest.response` property returns the response's body. It can be of the type `ArrayBuffer`, `Blob`, `Document`, JavaScript object, or a `DOMString`, depending of the value of `XMLHttpRequest.responseType` property.*

Comment: @born2gamble In this case, i'd suggest to use `newXHR.responseText`. You can explore the `newXHR` properties by using: `console.log(newXHR);`.

Comment: Thank You so much !  , and thank you for the link to the $.ajax version as well. I am going to start dissecting all of this. VERY much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd suggest to start learning `JavaScript` because jQuery, AngularJS, or any third party product, are based on `JavaScript`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "update.php?status=disp",false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

use `xmlhttp .send();` method for send a `request` to athore page

To avoid this `warning`, do not use `false` in perameter:

```
async: false
```

Comment: pass `async:true` instead of `false`

Comment: I tried putting “true” , the error goes away , but the page is blank.

Comment: so some mistake in your php code or you have no any print or return from php

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest? try the "new" [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). See: [Browser Support for Fetch](https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch).

Ok, it is not supported in IE. In my defense, IE 11 is the only version of IE in support, and if they have IE 11, they probably have Edge.

This is a very simple example:

```
fetch("example.com")
.then(
    function(response)
    {
        response.text()
        .then(
            function(result)
            {
                console.log(result);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Of couse, you would change `"example.com"` to your url.

The following is a more elaborate example, showcasing different options such as headers, request methods, redirections, control credentials (do you want to send cookies and http auth?) and catch exceptions. I recommend to read the MDN article on [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for more details.

Note: you can pass GET parameters in the url as expected. For a POST request you have to add the member `body` to the initialization of the `Request` object.

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest'); // #lies
var request = new Request(
    "example.com",
    {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers,
        mode: 'cors',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        cache: 'default',
        redirect: 'follow'}
);
fetch(request)
.then(
    function(response)
    {
        // response status
        console.log('ok: ' + response.ok);
        console.log('status: ' + response.status); //e.g: 200
        // response headers
        console.log('X-Header: ' + response.headers.get('X-Header'));
        // response url (redirections)
        console.log(response.url);
        // body as text
        response.text()
        .then(
            function(result)
            {
                console.log(result);
            }
        );
    }
)
.catch(
    function(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
);
```

Note: in the examples I use the method `text` to get the text of the body of the response. You may also use the method `json` that will get the body and parse it directly. There is also a `blob` method, which can be useful if the response is multimedia among other things.

Comment: Thank you for this, I will try this out after I fully understanding the first method. Its alot easier for me to learn while tinkering with the code as I read tutorials/videos about it.

Comment: @born2gamble I found a polyfill that will make (most of it) work in IE: [window.fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch). It uses [XMLHttpRequest internally](https://github.com/github/fetch/blob/master/fetch.js#L425) which may as well serve as case study.

Comment: Thank you I will check it out in depth soon