# Pikaday JavaScript with AutoPostBack TextBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, pikaday

I use [pikaday](/questions/tagged/pikaday)[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)for a calendar which displays value in `TextBox1`. This `TextBox` `AutoPostBack` property is `true`. Because when the date changes i make some calculations based on the date. The calendar appears. But the page makes a loop of `PostBacks`. When i make `TextBox1.AutoPostBack=false` it works fine but i loose calculations.

How can i use [pikaday](/questions/tagged/pikaday)[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)with `AutoPostBack` `TextBox`?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>'),
    format: 'yyyy/MM/dd',
    toString(date, format) {
      const day = date.getDate();
      const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
      const year = date.getFullYear();
      return `${year}/${month}/${day}`;
    },
    parse(dateString, format) {
      // dateString is the result of `toString` method
      const parts = dateString.split('/');
      const day = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
      const month = parseInt(parts[1] - 1, 10);
      const year = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
      return new Date(year, month, day);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you used before [UpdatePanels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: `UpdatePanels` technology 9 years ago... Better use native `XMLHttpRequest()` **JavaScript**.

Comment: @wael Don't use `AutoPostBack` in your ASP.NET `TextBox` Control and see this answer about `XMLHttpRequest()` **JavaScript**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47321853/call-php-function-in-ajax-synchronous-xmlhttprequest-deprecarted/47321930#47321930

Comment: @William-H-M I didn't use it before.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez i will check this link.

Comment: @wael I think as @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez is better to use AJAX It'll be better and you will not need to use `AutoPostback` you will just return your data and replace the value with some JavaScript