# how to do the auto fetch message without reloading the page by using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, mysqli

showing messages with:-

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE fromthe = '$email' and tothe='theadmin' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE fromthe = 'theadmin' and tothe='$email' order by id desc";
mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

unreaded message:-

```
$query = "SELECT status FROM chat WHERE status=0";
mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

`status == 0`  - **unreaded**

`status == 1` - **readed**..

how to do the auto fetch message without reloading the page by using ajax??

Comment: this is a broad question. Please look around the SO and you will get all that you want.

Comment: Use jquery ajax and create a PHP file that will handle request from it.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707648/using-jquery-ajax-to-retrieve-data-from-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Jquery Ajax to retrieve data from Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707648/using-jquery-ajax-to-retrieve-data-from-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

As the Database connection's already done. i prefer it to be in separate file (if your using php) i.e. **data.php** or anything else.

Use the jQuery script to fetch the data from that connection i.e. from database without reloading the page.
here's the code for that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
<div id="show"></div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     setInterval(function(){
        $('#show').load("data.php")
     }, 3000);
  });
<script>
```